# is there a way to identity which is parent and child through the y axis ticks

Tags: angular, highcharts

I wanted to know if there is property under highcharts yAxis[0].ticks to get to know if the tick.parameters.category is either a parent or child

Comment: Or is it possible to get ID of the category ?

Comment: Hi @user3361706, What exact relation do you want to check? Do you use `grouped_categories` plugin?

Comment: @ppotaczek for example based on which element is collapsed/expanded when i reload/re-create chart i will have to maintain the same state of collapsed of chart hence i need to know which elements in series has expanded. For that to know i can use tick.parameters.category which has all the visible y axis list , but what i actually want is among visible list which also says parent child relationship. And no i dont use grouped_categories plugin yet

Comment: I don't think I fully understand. Do you want to get the relation between ticks and points? Colud you reproduce that situation in some online code editor? You can start from: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/